# Change Browser settings by script

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, browser, google-chrome

Afaik, you can change/manipulate browser settings in Mozilla/Netscape browsers.
For Instance "netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('someprivilege');"

Of course the user gets informed about that and needs to verify the action.

My question is, do other browser have similar functionality? IE, Safari/Chrome ?

Kind Regards

--Andy

Comment: i'd avoid this, since it appears malicious to the user and could scare them away!

Comment: Normally this is a big nono. The browser and the user's current settings handle stuff such as privileges. It can make the browser behave unexpectedly to the user and thats is not a good thing. So if your application needs access to something the browser should ask the user its self or you could instruct the user on how to do this.

Comment: I don't know why you would even think this was possible.  If it where,  malicious people could wreak havoc!!

Comment: why did you want to change the permission anyway?

Comment: I need it do some cross-browser ajax calls. I can call 'UniversalBrowserRead' privilege in mozilla based browsers, now I'm looking for a way to do the same thing in IE and safari/chrome. This is not malicious, the user always MUST confirm that action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read about it here - http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html#privs

Also example available here: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-script-example.html

Browsers let extensions to interact with their core to certain level, but that's about it. You can read about Mozilla and Chrome extensions and see they interact with the browser through JavaScript, but this is only inside extensions, signed scripts and scripts located on user's hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

Did a quicky google after my comment, turns out no. Netscape is a pretty ancient browser anyway, since then securities been stepped up a fair few notches. anyway for a discussion here you go:

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/580772-how-change-browser-settings-dynamically-through-javascript