# using open.window in setInterval after promise resolve

Tags: javascript, browser, promise, setinterval

I have a chrome extension and I want the user to navigate to some page on button click, I get the URL from the server so I need to wait for the promise to resolve to know where to redirect the user to.
I tried doing it in the `then` section of the promise but realized it doesn't work because window open works only when triggered on the main thread as a result of user action (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026162/javascript-window-open-from-callback)).

One solution I came up with is using `setInterval` and for some reason it works. I don't know why and would love to understand better, maybe it's flaky and I shouldn't use it.

My code looks somewhat like this

```
const onClick = () => {
  const urls: string[] = []
  somePromise.then((url) => {
    urls[0] = url
  })

  setInterval(() => {
    const possibleURL = urls[0];
    if (possibleURL) {
      window.open(possibleURL, '_top')
    }
  }, 500)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you dont need a setInterval, just place the code which is inside it, in the then, under `urls[0] = url`

Comment: But it won't work, I can't window.open outside of user interaction because the browser will block it

Comment: np, in linked question it answer your question: *reason it works*, so this is a duplicate question, it seems it would also work without the setInterval, if you assign window.open to a var and then only set its location in the then callback

Comment: But I don't want to open a window and then change it's location, I want to present a loader and only when I get the url to open the new tab. I guess this is the difference and that's why it's not a duplication