# window.location.assign() not working in axios "then" in mobile browsers in production

Tags: reactjs, window, window.open, window.location

What I want my nextjs/react code to do:

When User clicks "Submit" button, a new tab is opened, then an axios request is sent that returns a response containing a URL generated by the API. I want that the newly opened tab gets redirected to the generated URL. I also need to keep the reference to the new tab because I need to implement some logic after the tab is closed.

[Here](http://theandystratton.com/2012/how-to-bypass-google-chromes-javascript-popup-blocker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470171/13477938) is why I first open a page and then redirect.

My code looks like that:

```
function onSubmit(formData: any) {
 const newPage = window.open('', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
 apiCall(newPage);
}

function apiCall(newPage: any) {
 axios({
   method: "post",
   url: "someAPI",
 }).then(function (success) {
   setTimeout(() => {
     newPage.location.assign(success.data.generatedURL);
   });

   const timer = setInterval(() => {
     if (newPage!.closed) {
       clearInterval(timer);
       // some logic after the new page was closed
     }
   }, 100);
 }).catch(function (error) {
   // some code here
 });
}
```

I also tried putting the `newPage.location.assign(success.data.generatedURL);` before of the `setTimeout` like that:

```
    newPage.location.assign(success.data.generatedURL);
    setTimeout(() => {
    });
```

The code works perfectly in my local environment across different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Brave) on both desktop and mobile devices. However, when deployed to production, the redirection **issue occurs specifically on mobile devices in production**. Although the new blank tab opens, it fails to redirect, despite the fact that I reach the "then" function and receive the correct redirect URL (checked with console.log)

Any help to solve the problem will be very appreciated!

**edit**: additional information - chrome://inspect **logs** in iPhone Chrome browser show the following **error**: ERROR TypeError: Load failed
ERROR Error: Failed to load script: / next/static/error-8353112a0135502.js