# Is there any way to change Browser print settings by Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I want to change print settings of browser by javascript or CSS.
Specifically I need to clear **Headers and Footers**.

For example in GoogleChrome when I press <kbd>Ctrl+p</kbd> the print dialog appears and there is an option named "**Headers and Footers**" that by default has checked in my browser (Chrome version 30.0.1599.101 m).

**1**. I don't need a cross-browser solution. It's enough for me if I could find a solution in one browser such as Google Chrome or firefox or IE.

**2**. I know that this is possible by using ActiveX but I don't want to use ActiveX.

Comment: Very, very unlikely without any additional browser extension. JavaScript isn't meant to manipulate browser preferences. Also, the there's no print API (and the CSS printing module is really old). After all, it's the user's choice what to print.

Comment: see as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a web page header/footer printed on every page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722437/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-web-page-header-footer-printed-on-every-page)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601761/change-browser-settings-by-script
*duplicate*

Comment: thank you Zeta. but I know that CSS2+ has some controls on printer settings http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-box.

Comment: thank you ijse. i read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page but my problem is something else.

Comment: re Cbroe -> the problem of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722437/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-web-page-header-footer-printed-on-every-page is other than my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide your header/footer by using css @media print querys...

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)

[css-print-media-query](http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/)

Comment: thank you alex but i tested the solution that described in http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/ and it did not work

Comment: this is really good and easy way. It works, unless your code is not correct.

Comment: This is assuming the OP means the Webpage body's Headers/Footer/Navigation when OP states the PRINTING Headers/Footers such as Title, Page Number, URL etc.