# Printing in Landscape mode in firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have 30 columns page and I need to print accommodating all columns in landscape mode. This one is just a test page where I try to print in landscape mode by rotating the page but it is not rotating the page.

```
<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>
<div id="rotate">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
<td>Testing Landscape</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<button class='gen_btn' onclick='PrintPage("#rotate")'>Print</button>

</body></html>
<script>function PrintPage(elem)
    {
        Popup(jQuery(elem).html(),elem);

    }

    function Popup(data,divName)
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Store Report', 'height=600,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<style>@media print{#rotate{transform:rotate(90deg);-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);-o-transform:rotate(90deg);transform:rotate(90deg);margin:10px;display: inline-block;}table{display:block;}}</style>');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
      mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.focus();

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Page still prints in potrait mode. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2wbo4w8v/

Comment: AFAIK you cannot programmatically set the browser print mode from JavaScript. The user will have to select Landscape mode themselves. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535002/is-there-any-way-to-change-browser-print-settings-by-javascript-or-css

Comment: Does it need to be javascript? You can do it with CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html