# IE settings through Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Is there any possibility to set the Internet Explorer settings by running  Javascript file..?

I want to set the following settings in IE through javascript/Jquery

1. Go to, ‘Tools’ -> ’Internet options’.
2. Under ‘General’ tab, click the ‘Settings’ button in the ‘Browsing History’ section.
3. Choose the radio button "Every time I visit the webpage".
4. Click ‘OK’ and restart the IE.

Comment: possible (kinda) duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601761/change-browser-settings-by-script

Comment: And see this link as well: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/580772-how-change-browser-settings-dynamically-through-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - it'd be a bit of a security hole if sites were able to do this...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the short answer is no: You can't do what you're asking for.

Javascript within the browser is heavily restricted to only being able to access resources for the actual page being viewed. This is an important security feature.

You cannot access other pages or other tabs. You cannot access parts of the browser UI outside of the page itself. You cannot run external programs.

Even if you could, the way you've described it wouldn't work anyway: The settings page you've described is specific to one particular version of IE. So your hypothetical program wouldn't work in any other browser or even any other version of IE.

However, more importantly, you need to ask yourself **why** you're asking for this.

The thing is that you're trying to solve a problem with your site. You've found something that resolves it, and you've asked a question about how to automate that. But you need to work backward a bit -- stop trying to work out how to automate this particular solution: you need to ask yourself whether there might be a different way of solving the original problem, which could be automated.

The fact is this: the config setting you're trying to change is for handling how the browser deals with caching of files. There are ways of changing the behaviour of caching that can be scripted by your site. You might want to look at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) for example.

The lesson here is this: Don't simply ask how to do something; explain *why* you're trying to do it as well. There might be an alternative solution that's better than the one you've thought of.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what Javascript designed to do. There is only a way to *read* browser setting from JS - using [signed scripts](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-script-example.html).